# reactable nested table is not displayed

Tags: r, shiny, reactable

I am building a R shiny app and wish to include a reactable with a nested table inside.
My current issue is that the nested table subset_df is not being displayed.

Here is the code:

```
  p<-reactable( df2,
                defaultSorted = "Question Category",
                columns = list(
                'Question Category' = colDef(
                 details = colDef(
                    #name='Description',
                                   details = function(index){
                                    htmltools::div(
                                      "Category Breakdown (%)",
                                       htmltools::tags$pre(paste(
                                        capture.output(
                                           print(subset_df[index,])
                                       ),
                                        ),
                                         collapse = '\n')
                                   )
                },
                                   align='left', width = 400, html=T
                  )
                ),
                 Favorability = 
                   colDef(cell = function(value,index){
                 #    htmltools::plotTag(plot_list[[index]], alt="plots")
                 }, width=260,align = "left")
               ), borderless = T, outlined = T,compact=T)
  p
```

I can't seem to understand what could be the problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Please see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: I have removed the images.

Comment: Another thing you might consider is to add `dput(df2)`: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example